# Get random products from category in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I have a class that returns 3 products from a category, these products are ordered by entity id and always returns the same 3 products from category X. I want to randomise them. in magento 1 you could do something like `$collection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');`, but this does not work in magento 2 anymore.

This is code that gets 3 products from category X.

```
protected $categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
)
{
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
}


public function getCategory($id)
{
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($id);
    return $category;
}

public function getProductsCollection($id)
{
    $r = array();
    $products = $this
        ->getCategory($id)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize(3)
        ->getItems();


    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $r[] = $product->getData();
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I suggest you use the `orderRand()` method.

You can do:

```
$productsCol = $this
        ->getCategory($id)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize(3);

$productsCol->getSelect()->orderRand();

$products = $productsCol->getItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code:
`$collection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');`

you have called php RAND() inside the quote('RAND()') which is invalid.

remove the quote for RAND()

your code itself should work, also put min & max length RAND($min, $max)

**But still I would recommend you to go with Magento way (same as Raphael answer)**

Comment: it is in quotes, because it is SQL expression...