# Random sort order in category page?

Tags: magento2

is it possible in Magento 2 to randomly show the products on a category page, like everytime the page is opened, random products are shown?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get random products from category in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113081/get-random-products-from-category-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you have to override the catelog_category_view.xml

And Change Block of getting listing of product collection.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

Change class from Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Random like below i have updated.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Random" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

After that make preference for _getProductCollection() for getting current category product like below.

```
/**
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
            $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => <<Category Id for getting current category product>>]);
            $this->_catalogLayer->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
            $collection->addStoreFilter();
            $numProducts = $this->getNumProducts() ? $this->getNumProducts() : 0;
            $collection->setPage(1, $numProducts);

            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

After that clear cache and check you getting product collection randomly.
Still if you have any query let me know.