# How do i get my products to appear in a random order on the category page?

Tags: magento2, catalog, category-products, porto-theme

At the minute, my products are showing in alphabetical order from the part number. When clicking on a category, I would like this to show in completely random order. Can anybody help with this? This using Magneto 2 and the theme Porto

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526893/changing-the-default-order-of-products-on-category-view

Comment: this will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/241595/66058